# cmd report(django and python) IntegrityError: column url is not unique

Tags: django, python-2.7, cmd

I am following a tutorial and seems am totally stuck, and previous questions like this don't have answers for mine.
the tutorial gives me this code;

```
>>> from bookmarks.models import *
>>>link1 = Link(url='http://www.packtpub.com/')
>>>link1.save()
>>>link2 = Link(url='http://www.example.com/')
>>>link2.save()
```

so the first two lines above go in well, but third line that says
"link1.save()", my cmd says "IntegrityError: column url is not unique"

my models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    #Create your models here
```

Comment: There maybe already the link with the same url. Check it: `Link.objects.filter(url='http://www.packtpub.com/')`

Comment: Show your models.py please

Comment: You might want to use the `get_or_create` helper method to avoid running into this error..

Comment: @karthikr, please am new, so do I apply this in command prompt? help me put down the whole code, thank you

Comment: You should first understand why you have such an error. The error message is clear enough, you set your url in the model with `unique=True`, which means you can't create any object with the  same url. What @karthikr suggested is that instead of using `save()` directly, use `get_or_create` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create.

Comment: @ShangWang, i have attempted to use your suggestion but this is the error message [traceback (most recent call last): File "(console)", line 1, in (module) AttributeError: 'Link' object has no attribute 'get_or_create'

Comment: Use `Link.objects.get_or_create(url="haha.com")`